# $_SESSION breaks parameters in url (in Angular project)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session

We've built a small project prototype for a client, which needs to be password protected because of our NDA. However - our use of the $_SESSION variable seems to break the parameters provided when entering from a secondary source even if we're logged in.

This is what we want to happen:

www.externalsite.com **->** oursite.com/#/route?param="value"

This is what happens:

externalsite.com **->** oursite.com/#/route?param="value" **->** oursite.com/#/defaultRoute

It would be awesome if anyone could tell me how to progress past this issue - either by providing actual solution or by linking to resources that might help or get us pointed in the right direction.

Here's our index.php

```
!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>prototype</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <?php require('access.php'); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

access.php:

```
<?php
$password = '43844e5d424a5c7d228f265f8c899d47a65cf52f';

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    } else {
        die ('Incorrect password');
    }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']): ?>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php
exit();
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `session_start()` function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags. You need to move it to `index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>prototype</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <?php require('access.php'); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- CONTENT -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the best kind of solution - I understand what I did wrong and how to fix it, and the implementation took literally two seconds. Thanks!